# Is it possible to differentiate between a zero value and a removed property in the Terraform Provider SDK?

Tags: terraform

I’m working on a custom provider and I have one specific resource which can accept several optional (and mutually exclusive) integer properties. However, I’ve noticed that when I set a property to zero, then remove the property, the SDK does not detect this as a change. In other words, I cannot differentiate between an explicit zero value and the removal of this property.

It seems like I'm just seeing a different symptom of the same underlying issue as discussed here https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/is-there-a-way-to-say-a-parameter-is-not-present-in-a-terraform-resource/18057/5

Any workarounds and assistance are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The old Terraform SDK, now called "SDKv2" in documentation, is a legacy system which was originally designed to work with Terraform v0.11 and earlier and is designed to support providers being used in both legacy Terraform versions and modern Terraform.

The concept of an attribute being totally unset (`null` in Terraform's terms) was new in Terraform v0.12 and so the old SDK does not support it. Any attribute that is defined in the schema must be assigned a non-null value of the appropriate type. As a consequence, the SDK also cannot distinguish between an attribute being set to the zero value of its type or never having been assigned a value at all.

[Terraform Plugin Framework](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/framework) is the modern replacement for "SDKv2" intended to support the full capabilities of modern Terraform, including the ability to set attributes explicitly to `null` to indicate that they are unset.

There are some current caveats with the new framework though, which might mean it's not a good choice for your current project. The Terraform SDK team has provided *[Which SDK Should I Use?](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/which-sdk)* as a guide to choose between them.